# how javascript interprets variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

How javascript interprets variables if it can be used without declaring?
Or if it is using a "var" to declare, how javascript know that this variable is for string, boolean.. etc.
Answers will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A javascript variable must be declared- but if the var keyword is omitted, the variable will be introduced with global scope. Calling or trying to read or use an undeclared variable throws an error.

Comment: try this one..<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
sampleVar = 3+6;
document.write(sampleVar);
</script>
</body>
</html> IT WILL OUTPUT 9 THOUGH I DIDN'T DECLARE 'sampleVar'

Comment: Yes, you did. See Kennebec comment.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will always try to infer the type of variable. `var x = 1` uses the *current* scope while `x=1` will head up the "scope chain" until it finds `x` or hits global scope where it is created.

Anyway, please don't tag your question [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Answer (score 0):

You can find many pages that cover this question. For example, try reading this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals